# How to create a Click method for static website

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, static-site

In the `nuxt` boilerplate (from [`create-nuxt-app`](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/installation/)) we have some simple buttons like this:

```html
<v-btn icon
  @click.stop="rightDrawer = !rightDrawer">
  <v-icon>mdi-menu</v-icon>
</v-btn>
.
.
.
<v-navigation-drawer
  v-model="rightDrawer"
  temporary
  fixed
>...</v-navigation-drawer>
```

And it `Vue.js` component is:

```js
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      rightDrawer: false,
    }
  }
}
```

But when I run the `nuxt generate` command, all these `@click`s don't work.

The [`generate`](https://nuxtjs.org/guide#static-generated-pre-rendering-) command is

> The big innovation of Nuxt.js

But I can't find any documentation of how to create an `EventListener`s for *Static Rendering*.

Comment: Can you provide more code please? Click directive should be working even in static

Comment: It is hard to get more code, because `nuxt` is mainly an engine, and the code is regular code.
That's why I explained that it was being restored to me by the boilerplate.

Comment: Just run the `create-nuxt-app` initialization commands and then run the `generate` command

Comment: could you show us your javascript code to your component ?

Comment: I added some code, I hope it will help. It is a very minimal sample, and the reproducing process is also simple- just `generate` the boilerplate. If it is not reproduced from the boilerplate, please tell me.